# pygameで作ったシューティングゲームで弾の数が多くなると動作が非常に遅くなる．

Tags: python, pygame

pygameを主に用いてシューティングゲームを作っています．弾の数が多くなると動作が非常に遅くなります．
原因はfor文を多用していることではないかと考えています．
下にコードを載せました．処理が早くなる方法を教えていただけると幸いです．

https://github.com/bobubobusuwawa/Nozaki_Ryo/tree/images

Comment: 長大なメソッド1つだけを掲載されても助言や回答は付きにくいと思われます。[再現可能な短いサンプルコードの書き方](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) を参考に、他の人が問題を再現・調査・検証出来る程度の規模にまで縮小するか、いっそどこかのサイトにプロジェクト全体を上げてリンクを貼った方がよいかもしれません。あとは、[Pythonのline_profilerとmemory_profilerの紹介](https://qiita.com/aratana_tamutomo/items/aa3b723a3dd7a44e45d6) のようなツールを使って、実際に何処が遅いのか計測してみるとか？

Comment: プロジェクトを上げてリンクを貼ってもらったようですが、他の人が(動作が非常に遅くなる)問題を再現出来る内容(ソースコード・サンプルデータ・再現手順の情報など)にはなっていないようです。それらを整えるか、それが難しいようなら自身でプロファイラ等で遅い箇所が何処か等を調査してみてください。

Comment: 実行するマシンの CPU 性能にも依るのでしょうが、`MISSILE_MAX` を `20000`(元の10倍)にすると遅くなりますね。まぁ、自機ミサイル用のリストの再利用の仕方がちょっと…といったところでしょうか。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

弾の座標などを管理するリストの元の数を必要以上に大きくしていたことが原因でした．
小さくすると動作しました．